# Is it possible to set up and watch a game between just computer AI opponents?

Tags: civilization-5

No human players, just AI and have the ability to scroll around and see what the AIs are doing with the turn management being also automated, so the AIs just end turn when they are done. Oh, and all of this hopefully without any sort of fog of war.

This way, I can see how the AI manages resources and units and maybe learn a thing or two as a civ newb.

Comment: The best way to learn is to play against super easy computers.  Watching computers doesn't work very well, because they get bonuses players don't.

Comment: Another great way to learn to play is watching lets plays on youtube. For example, MadDjinn has an excellent series of 20+ videos called "beyond the monument" featuring mid to advanced level strategies.

Comment: personally i've learned more from harder computers then i ever have playing easy comps. unless your just having a hard time with the basics. If you wanna see how the computer manages resources put your workers on automatic improvements.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I found:

[CIVfanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=468967)

It seems to be possible by downloading the CIV 5 SDK called Fire Tune. I'm sorry for not being able to provide you with more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry no the game requires at least 1 human player in order to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. There needs to be a human player to start the game, but all you have to do is step out of the way. One way to achieve it is to use the in-game-editor mod to delete your initial city and hide some inaccessible units. Then, all is left to do is to end turns and observe.

For an example, see the Civilization V AI only series by reddit user [thenyanmaster](http://www.reddit.com/user/thenyanmaster):

- [Link to setup and first installment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJEfA.jpg)
- [Link to list of all published installments](http://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/2u58b5/thenyanmaster_ai_civ_game_index/)